# Wpf - Textblock color change column wise on random input

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, textblock

Currently this is my XAML Listview:
i've done alot of searching but i couldn't find the solution to this, your help will be appreciated, thanks.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView_data" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,20,5" Width="712" Height="357">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="lvgvc">
                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="black"></SolidColorBrush>
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and this is Code-Behind:

```
    //received data in DataTable (dt)
    for(int i=0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
                        gvc.Header = "Column"+i;
                        gvc.Width = 100;
                        gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("column"+i);
                        lvgvc.Columns.Add(gvc);      
                    }

                listView_data.Items.Clear();
                listView_data.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Listview creates the columns and populates the datatTable. But the rows are completely white. I can select 6 rows in listview as there are six rows in dataTable and while debugging DataTable shows the correct data in it. How can i make the textblock color black in listview. i want textblock according to the random input column wise.

Comment: Look at setting ListView.ItemContainerStyle. Google for actual examples of how to style ListView items. Don't just type arbitrary XAML in arbitrary places. That method could take years. Find a working example. Base your code on a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Path of the DisplayMemberBinding should be set to the name of the column:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
    gvc.Header = "Column" + i;
    gvc.Width = 100;
    gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName);
    lvgvc.Columns.Add(gvc);
}

listView_data.Items.Clear();
listView_data.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

And the colour of the text in the columns can be changed by defining an ItemContainerStyle in the XAML markup:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView_data">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="lvgvc"/>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

If you want different colours in different columns you could create a DataTemplate for each column programmatically:

```
const string dataTemplate = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><TextBlock Text=\"{{Binding  {0}}}\" Foreground=\"{1}\" /></DataTemplate>";

for (int i = 0; i<dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string colour = "Green"; ///change this one based on your colouring logic...
    DataTemplate template = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(string.Format(dataTemplate, dt.Columns[0].ColumnName, colour)) as DataTemplate;
    GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn() { CellTemplate = template };
    gvc.Header = "Column" + i;
    gvc.Width = 100;
    lvgvc.Columns.Add(gvc);
}

listView_data.Items.Clear();
listView_data.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```